# Missing illustrations in WIPO patent application

Tags: international, google-patents, wipo, patent-figures

In reference to the patent: [WO 2013/153173 A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2013153173A1)

Where can I find illustrations for this patent?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the link from Google to [Espacenet](https://www.google.com/url?id=b4vYCAABERAJ&q=http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio%3FCC%3DWO%26NR%3D2013153173A1%26KC%3DA1%26FT%3DD&usg=AFQjCNEnxuwS_prHOHztulTi6jR4X9XZOw), then click on [EP Register](https://register.epo.org/espacenet/regviewer?CY=EP&DB=REG&LG=en&PN=WO2013153173&locale=en_EP), click on [All Documents](https://register.epo.org/application?number=EP13719760&lng=en&tab=doclist) and select (and click "Download Documents") the "International publication of the A1 Pamphlet" to get the full WIPO patent application with figures (or select the "Priority document (electronically transmitted)" to get the original German application).

Answer (score 0):

Google sometimes doesnot provide drawings or pdf in such cirumstances please use external link to directly go to patent database and download original scan copy which will contain all information like drawings etc.

For example in this case:-

[image]